# Grey wire in ceiling rose

Tags: light-fixture

My son disconnected ceiling rose on bottom level to fit new light and was sure he knew where they went back however on fitting new light the new light stayed on;we connected back to how he thought they were and ceiling pendant works as it should as do other lights however when we connect new light it stays on.if we disconnect the GREY wire completely on new light scenario all lights work as they should,
Can we leave this grey wire unconnected or should it be connected to one of other wires either in loop or on neutral side of connections.
He thinks it was joined to black live originally which in that scenario light only works fine with original pendant???

Comment: More information would make it easier to answer your question.  Please edit your question and tell us what country you are in, describe ALL the wires you see including ones in the ceiling box but not connected to your light, describe how they were connected to the old one and to the new one.  PIctures would help, of the old and the new.  It sounds like your grey wire is unswitched power.  It probably shouldn't be connected to your light, but it probably shouldn't be disconnected either.  We need more info please.

Comment: Can you post photos of the ceiling rose in question? Also, where are you on this planet?